# Adjusted cumulative incidence curve in proc phreg

Tags: sas

I am struggling with drawing adjusted cumulative incidence curve in proc phreg.

While searching, I found a paper that mentioned using the following SAS macro called %CIFCOX.
[Link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3377442/)

But I couldn't find it on the web site.

If anyone knows a code or macro that can draw such graphs, could you please share it?

Many thanks in advance.

[This is what I wanted to draw.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dp5f.png)